# Join three MySQL queries to one to get it faster

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have three MySQL queries, how to join it to one to get result faster? Is it possible to do it with single query and if it then if it was faster than separate three queries? (I can have up to 1.5M records in table - measurements from 3 month period)

- `id` - auto increment, int
- `phase` - tinyint, could be only 1,2 or 3
- `time` - datetime, time is same for each phase group 1,2,3
- `voltage` - float

Sample data:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+---------+
| id | time                | phase | voltage |
+----+---------------------+-------+---------+
|  1 | 2021-01-31 19:55:01 |     1 |  235.77 |
|  2 | 2021-01-31 19:55:01 |     2 |  237.94 |
|  3 | 2021-01-31 19:55:01 |     3 |  224.63 |
|  4 | 2021-01-31 19:55:06 |     1 |  236.41 |
|  5 | 2021-01-31 19:55:06 |     2 |  238.17 |
|  6 | 2021-01-31 19:55:06 |     3 |  224.61 |
|  7 | 2021-01-31 19:55:11 |     1 |  236.45 |
|  8 | 2021-01-31 19:55:11 |     2 |  237.87 |
|  9 | 2021-01-31 19:55:11 |     3 |   223.4 |
+----+---------------------+-------+---------+
```

Query #1:

```
SELECT time, voltage AS L1
FROM measurements
WHERE phase = 1
ORDER BY id
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT time, voltage AS L2
FROM measurements
WHERE phase = 2
ORDER BY id
```

Query #3:

```
SELECT time, voltage AS L3
FROM measurements
WHERE phase = 3
ORDER BY id
```

Result after should be like that:

```
+----+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| id | time                |   L1   |   L2   |   L3   |
+----+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 | 2021-01-31 19:55:01 | 235.77 | 237.94 | 224.63 |
|  2 | 2021-01-31 19:55:06 | 236.41 | 238.17 | 224.61 |
|  3 | 2021-01-31 19:55:11 | 236.45 | 237.87 | 223.4  |
+----+---------------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

**EDIT**: after all, I got a query:

```
SELECT 
    time,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(phase = 1, voltage, NULL)) AS 'L1',
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(phase = 2, voltage, NULL)) AS 'L2',
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(phase = 3, voltage, NULL)) AS 'L3'
FROM 
    `measurements`
GROUP BY 
    time
```

and now results looks like:

```
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| time                | L1                 | L2                 | L3                 |
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+  

| 2021-01-31 19:55:01 | 235.77000427246094 | 237.94000244140625 | 224.6300048828125  |
| 2021-01-31 19:55:06 | 236.41000366210938 | 238.1699981689453  | 224.61000061035156 |
| 2021-01-31 19:55:11 | 236.4499969482422  | 237.8699951171875  | 223.39999389648438 |
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Why now voltage values are so inaccurate, all voltage stored values are with max 2 number after decimal point I don't do any math in query... then why got this strange values?

Comment: You probably want different phase conditions in your queries.

Comment: Timestamp grouping is difficult. Say L1 is at 19:55:01.999999 and L2 at 19:55:02.000001 - should they be grouped together?

Comment: @jarlh datetime for each 3 phase are identical, then they could be easy grouped together, but how to split voltage to 3 new column?

Comment: @XnIcRaM Is the WHERE condition correct? From intuition I think you want Q2 to check for phase=2 and Q3 to check for phase=3?

Comment: GROUP BY timestamp. Use case expressions to pick the different L1, L2 and L3 values.

Comment: This question sounds like the questioned and answered [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Comment: It's help but..., my query is now `SELECT 
  time,
  GROUP_CONCAT( if(phase=1,voltage,NULL) ) AS 'L1',
  GROUP_CONCAT( if(phase=2,voltage,NULL) ) AS 'L2',
  GROUP_CONCAT( if(phase=3,voltage,NULL) ) AS 'L3'
FROM `measurements`
GROUP BY time` but why I get all values like `223.39999389648438` when all voltage values in my table are max  two decimal digits after the point

Comment: Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66041767/edit) with the query instead of posting in comments. Thanks

Comment: Show us the incoming data.  3 separate rows?

Comment: Look at other "pivot" questions; find one with a `CASE`.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend to change the structure a bit.
What would you say for:

- table `measurements` with columns:

  - id
  - time
- table `measurements_results` with columns:

  - id
  - measurement_id
  - phase
  - voltage

Table `measurements_results` must have foreign key on `measurement_id`.
On `phase` column you could put regular index.

Than the query will look like this:

```
select m.id measurement_id, m.time, mr_l1.voltage L1, mr_l2.voltage L2, mr_l3.voltage L3
from measurements m
left join measurements_results mr_l1
    on mr_l1.measurement_id = m.id
    and mr_l1.phase = 1
left join measurements_results mr_l2
    on mr_l2.measurement_id = m.id
    and mr_l2.phase = 2
left join measurements_results mr_l3
    on mr_l3.measurement_id = m.id
    and mr_l3.phase = 3
```

[Edit] Left joins are for safety because this db structure does not ensure you will always have voltage for all 3 phases. So you could add `coalesce(voltage, 0)` to not get null in result.

Comment: No.  He will just come back and say that performance is bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a simple way with `group by` and using `CASE` statements:

```
SELECT time, max(case phase
                    when 1 then voltage
                    else 0
                  end) as L1, 
              max(case phase
                    when 2 then voltage
                    else 0
                  end) as L2, 
              max(case phase
                    when 3 then voltage
                    else 0
                  end) as L3
FROM measurements
group by time
ORDER BY time
```

Comment: I think that ELSE is excess in all CASEs... absent value and zero value is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `GROUP_CONCAT()` has to convert the values to strings.  It looks like they are floating point values -- so the conversion is rarely accurate.

If you really wanted to convert to a string, then use `FORMAT()` to get the format you want.  However, I would preserve the original type using:

```
SELECT time,
       MAX(CASE WHEN phase = 1 THEN voltage END) AS L1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN phase = 2 THEN voltage END) AS L2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN phase = 3 THEN voltage END) AS L3
FROM measurements
GROUP BY time;
```

Notes:

- You don't generally need backticks on identifiers, such as `measurements`.
- I much, much prefer `CASE` because it is standard SQL, so I replaced that.
- Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  It is too easy to confuse them with strings.  And, they are not needed either.

Comment: same problem, both `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `CASE` give numbers with many digits after decimal point

Comment: @XnIcRaM . . . As the answer says, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` with `FORMAT()` to convert the number to the representation you want.

Comment: I know that but why it was happend it's strange for me

Comment: @XnIcRaM . . . It is strange that it is happening in these queries, but you see the data okay.  The root of the problem is the floating point format.  You probably should be using numeric/decimal.

Answer (score 0):

I'll argue for fixing it on input; this will probably be better in the long run.  But... What other `SELECTs` do you need to do against the data?

```
CREATE TABLE measurements (
    dt DATETIME NOT NULL,
    v1 DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,     -- or whatever is appropriate; FLOAT is a reasonable option
    v2 DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
    v3 DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (dt)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Notes:

- If there are other columns, we need to know about them
- If the data comes in as 3 records, then either collect them and do a single `INSERT` or do 1 `INSERT` and 2 `UPDATEs`.  For this latter case, consider `NULL`.
- "235.77000427246094" has to do with when MySQL decides to perform computations in `DOUBLE`.  Doing pivoting a different way avoids such.